# JSTL <x:if> or-Operation

Tags: xml, jsp, jstl, jsp-tags

currently I have a JSP with this expression:

```
<x:if select="$record[principal=$pageScope:uk]">
```

"uk" is a given parameter. What I want to do is pass the if when "principal" matches the parameter OR when its empty.

Something like this:

```
<x:if select="$record[principal=$pageScope:uk] || empty $pageScope:uk">
```

but this is not working and I could'nt find any documentation about  and OR-Operations.

Thank You

Markus

Edit: Putting the Value in a Variable and comparing it afterwards with c:if was my solution:

```
<x:set var="principalUK" select="string($record/principal/text())"/>
<c:if test="${principalUK eq param.userKey || empty param.userKey}" >
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<x:if test="$record[principal=$pageScope:uk]  || empty $pageScope:uk">
```

Comment: "According to the TLD or the tag file, attribute select is mandatory for tag if". That's what Tomcat told me. And the Description of the JSTL says there is no "test" in x:if only in c:if

Comment: x or c is the prefix we use, give x as the prefix for jstl core library     <%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jstl/core" %>

Comment: I'm sorry, but why on earth would i define me prefix for the CORE library to "x" like XML? That sounds highly confusing for anyone who reads the code. I import and use both of them. But i cant evaluate an XPath in c:if, thats why i used x:if

Comment: @markus what you said makes sense, however in your question you should clarify as well that you are working with JSTL XML by importing `<%@ taglib prefix="x" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/xml" %>`